# Firebase Console: Using screen_view as event for audience possible?

Tags: firebase, mobile, google-analytics, analytics

There is a possibility to use the the firebase event **screen_view** to define an audience?

When I'm coming from dashboard (clicking on **VIEW SCREEN_VIEW EVENT DETAILS** button) I'm seeing that screen_view is treated as an event

[image: coming from dashboard]

But when I'm coming from **events menu**, the screen_view is not listed

[image]

When I tried to create a new **audience** *screen_view* event is not available

[image]

It is this possible without need to actually add a custom event?

Answer (score 0):

You should indeed be able to use screen views to create a user audience but you don't seem to have any screen_view events.

The data displayed when you view it from dashboard is actually coming from another, separate, event named user_engagement. If your application is on iOS it is possible that firebase screen reporting is disabled in Info.plist.

See [Disabling firebase automatic screen reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44746794/disabling-firebase-automatic-screen-reporting)

---

Comment: If you see my first posted images, at the bottom-right you'll see the tracked screen_views. Anyway if they are tracking automatically the screens, why do I need extra to track the same event? I do not see the event you mentioned neither (_engagement_)


Extract from Documentation:  _Google Analytics for Firebase tracks screen transitions and attaches information about the current screen to events,..._
https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews

Comment: Yes, but those (screen class + time spent) are provided by the user_engagement event.

The user_engagement event provides information about where and how long the user does something and is not equal to a screen_view. The screen_view event is used to track how the user is navigating through the app and has additional parameters like previous_screen. You could in theory have multiple user_engagement events on the same screen.

I do not know why Google does not show user_engagement in the events list, but it is intentionally excluded.

Comment: It might be worth noting that if you have your Firebase instance connected to BigQuery you can access user_engagement data there. You won't be able to create an audience per se, but you might be able to get the data you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are event names in Firebase Analytics which are reserved and cannot be used. Here is a list of the following reserved Firebase event names such as screen_view. The Android Studio also gives you a warning in case of using reserved firebase analytics names as events.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event