# Firebase setCurrentScreen() as first event doesn't log proper values

Tags: android, firebase, events, logging, firebase-analytics

I have `ViewPager` with `Tabs` so I log custom screen names to Firebase Analytics when the user switches between tabs. **The problem is that my first event isn't logged**. Why?

Can it happen because automatic `screen_view` event is logged (without `firebase_screen` argument which I need to properly analyze the data) and this automatic event has "higher priority" and overrides my event?

Or maybe I log my first event in the wrong place (`onCreate` method) ?

Simplified code:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        (...)

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(SecondActivity.this).setCurrentScreen(SecondActivity.this, getTabNameForLogging(position), null);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            }
        });

        //send event because onPageSelected isn't triggered at activity/viewpager start-up
        FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).setCurrentScreen(this, "TAB 0", null);

    }

    private String getTabNameForLogging(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "TAB 0";
            case 1:
                return "TAB 1";
            case 2:
                return "TAB 2";
            default:
                return "invalid position";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you disabled the automatic screen view tracker? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44746794/disabling-firebase-automatic-screen-reporting

Comment: How to do this in android? And as I can see from the thread: "Google Analytics for Firebase does NOT support the case of manual-only screen reporting". But maybe in Android version it works different.

Comment: My bad. I didn't notice that this is about Android, not iOS

Answer (score 1):

It could be that firebase cannot setCurrentScreen because it does not get an activity from SecondActivity.this in onCreate(). Something similar has happened to me.

There are workarounds like putting it in onGlobalLayout() or onResume() instead.

Comment: I changed `SecondActivity.this` to `this` and still dosen't work. My original post wast edited.

Answer (score 1):

the reason might be sending that event too soon after new activity is created. Placing the call in onResume or onGlobalLayout is not the solution, but a workaround.

When I was debugging similar issue with my project, I found that there are some logs being printed as follows:

> V/FA: Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent.

My understanding is that events have to be sent with at least 1000ms interval (keep in mind that library is sending automatic events when new activity is created).

I wish it was more documented, I have spent so much time on issues related to missing analytic events...

Answer (score -2):

The reason of this is because, quoting the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews):

> Manually tracking screens is useful if your app does not use a
>   separate UIViewController or Activity for each screen you may wish to
>   track, such as in a game.

Therefore, you can't actually change it within an `Activity` with tabs, it's unique per `Activity`. Also, if you set `screenClassOverride` to `null` you will revert it to default, please see below:

> The name of the screen class. By default this is the class name of the
>   current Activity. Set to null to revert to the default class name.

I suggest you to use `view_item` for this need of yours within the tabs and send that instead uniquely, that fits better for your purpose. But if you are wondering why it's not firing the first one just try it like this on `onCreate`:

```
FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).setCurrentScreen(SecondActivity.this, "SecondActivity");
```

Comment: `.setCurrentScreen()` takes three arguments tho.