# How can I manually trigger a screen_view event in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

Currently we're using Firebase in our iOS app.

I'm curious wether it is possible (and valid) to disable automatic reporting (using `FirebaseScreenReportingEnable`) and to call `Analytics.logEvent` (with the required params) manually.

Something in the lines of

```
Analytics.logEvent("screen_view", parameters: [
  "firebase_event_origin": "auto",
  "firebase_previous_class": "PrevClass",
  "firebase_previous_id": "1",
  "firebase_previous_screen": "PrevScreen",
  "firebase_screen": "NewScreen",
  "firebase_screen_class": "NewClass",
  "firebase_screen_id": "2",
])
```

Comment: Please find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44768905/2520509

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't manually trigger screen_view event. However, you can disable automatic screen recording via adding below key to your targets plist;

```
<key>FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled</key>
<false/>
```

and send a Manuel report to Firebase with custom event name;

```
 func sendScreenDataToGA(screenName: String) {
    Analytics.logEvent("screen_tracking_view", parameters: [
        "screen_name": screenName
    ])
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't be able to do funnelling or A/B testing using by looking at the `screen_name` though, right?

Comment: I'm not sure how you can do A/B testing on Firebase.

Answer (score 3):

You can [track screens by explicit calls](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews#manually_track_screens) by calling `setScreenName()`:

```
Analytics.setScreenName(screenName, screenClass: screenClass)
```

Comment: But this does not achieve "disable automatic reporting " and also sends screen data which is automatically set by Firebase.

Comment: There were two questions: 1) how to explicitly track screen views, 2) how to disable implicit reporting. Since you already answered #2, I provided the correct answer (and a reference to the docs) for #1.