# Analytics screen reporting is disabled. UIViewController transitions will not be logged

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have set up an iOS app with Firebase and am receiving the following error:

"Analytics screen reporting is disabled. UIViewController transitions will not be logged."

What is the name of the key I need to add/update in the Info.plist? I have been unable to find this specific error online although this link seems to be related if it is of any use for my question.

[Disabling firebase automatic screen reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44746794/disabling-firebase-automatic-screen-reporting)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This `FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED` is the key you need to add it in you `Info.plist` Make sure you add it in Your Info.Plist Not the one with the name `GoogleService-Info.plist`

```
<key>FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED</key>
<true/>
```

Also you can use this method to override the value you set in your plist

```
Analytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true)
```

For more information click the link below : -

https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/configure-data-collection

Comment: Where do you put this code you wrote with the <key> tags? I was thinking I just add it directly to the Info.plist file

Comment: Okay i get your point, Right click on the Info.plist file and open as-> source code. Then you'll see an xml file put the key-value pair there also make sure you don't break the xml format.