# How do I update the manifest for Google Analytics on Android?

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, android-manifest, firebase-analytics

I am trying to disable automatic screen reporting for Google Firebase Analytics. In the [Firebase Blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/08/google-analytics-manual-screen-view.html), it states

> On Android, set google_analytics_automatic_screen_reporting_enabled to “false” in your manifest.

How should I change my `AndroidManifest.xml` to follow the above instructions?

I modified the `manifest` tag like this, but I'm not sure if this is correct.

```
<manifest
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  google_analytics_automatic_screen_reporting_enabled="false"
  package="com.myapp.name"
>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to add it as `<meta-data>` inside of the `<application>`:

```
<manifest>
    <application>
        <meta-data
            android:name="google_analytics_automatic_screen_reporting_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
        <!-- ... -->
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Answer is correct, but not working because of this bug: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2225 (Firebase analytics v19.0.0).

Answer (score 1):

Since u asked for android but for others posting the key for iOS also.
On iOS, set FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to “NO” in your info.plist. On Android, set google_analytics_automatic_screen_reporting_enabled to “false” in your manifest.
For Android: In AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<meta-data
           android:name="google_analytics_automatic_screen_reporting_enabled"
           android:value="false" />
       
   
For iOS: In Info.plist file
   

<key>FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled</key>
       <false/>
```